# Oracle - How to get first Monday of the year?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get first Monday of the year?

```
select TRUNC(date'2015-01-01','YYYY')
      ,NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(date'2015-01-01','YEAR')+1,'MONDAY')
from dual;

01-JAN-2015 05-JAN-2015
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To account for the possibility of the year starting on a Monday, you need to go back to the last day of the previous year, before going forward to the next Monday; for the current year:

```
next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') - 1, 'Monday')
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39968). This gives the first Monday of 2007 as January 1st; without the -1 adjustment [it would say the 8th](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39969).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`select next_day(round(sysdate,'yyyy'),'mon')
from dual;`

Comment: This will only work in the first half of the year; in the second half of the year it will give you the first Monday of *next* year. (Or the second Monday, if the first day of the year is itself a Monday.)